# Prevent Django from parsing incorrect TIMESTAMP field

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a sqlite database (from an iOS application) similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE ZSPL ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ZWHEN TIMESTAMP, ZWHEN2 real)

1, 492445270.121238, 492445270.121238
2, 492445270.871551, 492445270.871551
```

I was hoping to build a Django (v1.10) model to work with it [following these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects):

```
APPLE_EPOCH = datetime(year=2001, month=1, day=1, hour=0, second=0)


def apple_time_to_datetime(apple_time):
  if isinstance(apple_time, datetime):
      return apple_time
  return APPLE_EPOCH + timedelta(seconds=float(apple_time))


class AppleDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        return apple_time_to_datetime(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        return apple_time_to_datetime(value)

class Spl(models.Model):
    when = AppleDateTimeField(db_column='ZWHEN')
```

However this errors because `parse_datetime` registered by the converters [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#) attempts to parse the numeric value in `ZWHEN`.  If these converters are commented out then it errors on the dbapi2 `convert_timestamp` function [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/sqlite3/dbapi2.py#l66).

Similarly, when the `db_column='ZWHEN'` is changed to `db_column='ZWHEN2'` it errors because a datetime converter is registered before the custom converters.  You can see this in the value of `conv` on [this line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py#L785).

I was wondering if there was anyway to get around this problem and have the custom `from_db_value` converter called first?

Temporarily I've resorted to using the copied `ZWHEN2` instead of the `ZWHEN` field and editing the [`get_converters`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py#L778) function to read:

```
converters[i] = (field_converters + backend_converters, expression)
```

instead of:

```
converters[i] = (backend_converters + field_converters, expression)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer I'm looking for as it involves changes to the Django library but at least it doesn't involve editing the source code itself.

In the same file as the model I've added the following lines:

```
from django.db.backends.sqlite3.base import Database, decoder

Database.register_converter(str("timestamp"), decoder(apple_time_to_datetime))
Database.register_converter(str("TIMESTAMP"), decoder(apple_time_to_datetime))
```

The seems to have "solved" the problem.